# What is the conventional way to reuse methods across presenters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is a convention for reusing methods between presenters?

For example, say an app has the following presenters

```
class UserPresenter < BasePresenter
end
class AdminPresenter < BasePresenter
end
class EventPresenter < BasePresenter
end
```

User and Admin both have avatars. What is the correct way to share an `avatar` method between the User and Admin presenter?

One solution might be inheriting from an AvatarPresenter

```
class UserPresenter < AvatarPresenter
end
class AdminPresenter < AvatarPresenter
end
class EventPresenter < BasePresenter
end
class AvatarPresenter < BasePresenter
end
```

Which works OK in this simple example. But what if things become more complex in the future (e.g., an additional method shared between Admin and Event).

I suppose I'm looking to share Concerns between Presenters. Is this a conventional approach, and if so what would a template implementation look like? All my attempts are raising `method not found` errors.

Comment: Modules are probably what you're after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is [traits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_programming)). In Ruby this takes the form of module mixins.

```
module Avatar
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
    base.class_eval do
      # in this block you are operating on the singleton class
      # where the module is included
    end
  end

  def an_instance_method_from_avatar
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def a_class_method_from_avatar
    end
  end
end

class UserPresenter
  include Avatar
end

class AdminPresenter
  include Avatar
end
```

This lets us create reusable components that can composed in many different ways. [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) takes the pattern above and simplifies it:

```
module Avatar
  # modules can be extended by other modules
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # in this block you are operating on the singleton class
    # where the module is included
  end

  class_methods do
    def a_class_method_from_avatar
    end
  end

  def an_instance_method_from_avatar
  end
end
```

Inheritance (class based) on the other hand should only really be used if an object is a true subtype of its parent. While you could argue that an AdminPresenter is a presenter with an avatar this would lead to a really convoluted class diagram down the road if you need to add other functionality.

Comment: This really applies to any kind of objects in Ruby and not just presenters.

Comment: thanks @max. where would you expect to find presenter traits/modules in Rails app? `app/presenters/modules`? `app/traits`? Is there a convention for this?

Comment: Did I understand your last paragraph correctly? "inheritance ..... should only be used". This is referring to the `UserPresenter < AvatarPresenter < BasePresenter` idea, not to the modules you describe in your answer?

Comment: Presenters are not really a part of a typical rails application. So there is no convention. You might want to place them `app/presenters/concerns` as that mirrors `app/models/concerns` and `app/controllers/concerns`.

Comment: Yes I was talking about class based inheritance. For example `class AdminPresenter < UserPresenter` is a valid case for inheritance if an admin is  a type of user and you can swap an instance of `UserPresenter` with `AdminPresenter`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle